# How can I return a character array from a function in C?

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, character

is that even possible?
Let's say that I want to return an array of two characters

```
char arr[2];
arr[0] = 'c';
arr[1] = 'a';
```

from a function. What type do I even use for the function? Is my only choice to use pointers and void the function? So far I've tried having a char* function or a char[]. Apparently you can only have functions of char(*[]). The only reason I want to avoid using pointers is the fact that the function has to end when it encounters a "return something;" because the value of "something" is a character array (not a string!) that might change size depending on the values I pass into the function through the main function. Thanks to anyone who responds in advance.

Comment: Function should return char *. What problem do you foresee?

Comment: I tried that but it seg faults everytime. I just use a char* function and return arr; and it segfaults when I try to output. Also gcc warns me that I'm trying to return integer without a cast when I return the array from above

Comment: @AnnoyingQuestions because an array when declared inside a function it's allocated in the stack frame of the function, hence when returning it, it's deallocated with the function right after returning it.

Comment: Technically, It is not explicitly deallocated. Just that using it after the function can cause undefined behaviour because functions called after this function could have overwritten the contents of the memory location( in the stack )

Comment: If the three lines of code you gave us are in a function, then you're trying to return a local after it goes out of scope, so yes, that will segfault. The fact that it's an array has nothing to do with it.

Comment: A character array and a string are exactly the same thing, except that a string has a NULL character at the end.  They're both just consecutive bytes in memory.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You've got several options:

**1)** Allocate your array on the **heap** using `malloc()`, and return a pointer to it. You'll also need to keep track of the length yourself:

```
void give_me_some_chars(char **arr, size_t *arr_len)
{
    /* This function knows the array will be of length 2 */
    char *result = malloc(2);

    if (result) {
        result[0] = 'c';
        result[1] = 'a';
    }

    /* Set output parameters */
    *arr = result;
    *arr_len = 2;
}

void test(void)
{
    char *ar;
    size_t ar_len;
    int i;

    give_me_some_chars(&ar, &ar_len);

    if (ar) {
        printf("Array:\n");
        for (i=0; i<ar_len; i++) {
            printf(" [%d] = %c\n", i, ar[i]);
        }
        free(ar);
    }
}
```

**2)** Allocate space for the array on the **stack** of the *caller*, and let the called function populate it:

```
#define ARRAY_LEN(x)    (sizeof(x) / sizeof(x[0]))

/* Returns the number of items populated, or -1 if not enough space */
int give_me_some_chars(char *arr, int arr_len)
{
    if (arr_len < 2)
        return -1;

    arr[0] = 'c';
    arr[1] = 'a';

    return 2;
}

void test(void)
{
    char ar[2];
    int num_items;

    num_items = give_me_some_chars(ar, ARRAY_LEN(ar));

    printf("Array:\n");
    for (i=0; i<num_items; i++) {
        printf(" [%d] = %c\n", i, ar[i]);
    }
}
```

**DO NOT TRY TO DO THIS**

```
char* bad_bad_bad_bad(void)
{
    char result[2];      /* This is allocated on the stack of this function
                            and is no longer valid after this function returns */

    result[0] = 'c';
    result[1] = 'a';

    return result;    /* BAD! */
}

void test(void)
{
    char *arr = bad_bad_bad_bad();

    /* arr is an invalid pointer! */
}
```

Comment: There's another perfectly valid option: `return "ca";`.

Comment: @DanKorn Sure, but I think you're drastically over-simplifying the problem.  It's safe to say the OP's code is more complicated than returning some fixed values (there would be no point).

Comment: The problem stated in the original post is itself very simple.  Whether there's more complexity behind it, I can't say.  You're making an assumption.

Comment: Can I do following?  
`int comm_read_info(int file_i2c, unsigned char* buffer)  
{  
    unsigned char* read_buffer = malloc(57); /* this func knows that it is 57 bytes */  
    if (i2c_read_bytes(file_i2c, read_buffer, sizeof(read_buffer)) != 0)  
    {  
        *buffer = result;  
        return 0;  
    }  
    return -1;  
}`

Comment: @Elephant Comments aren't for asking questions - long segments of code are unreadable. You should [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). But no, that's not going to work; you have a type mismatch here: `*buffer = result` You need `comm_read_info(int file_i2c, unsigned char** buffer)` which returns out a pointer to the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

You can return a pointer for the array from a function, however you can't return pointers to local arrays, the reference will be lost.

So you have 3 options:

1. Use a global variable:

   ```
    char arr[2];

    char * my_func(void){
        arr[0] = 'c';
        arr[1] = 'a';
        return arr;
    }
   ```
2. Use dynamic allocation (the caller will have the responsibility to free the pointer after using it; make that clear in your documentation)

   ```
    char * my_func(void){

        char *arr;    
        arr = malloc(2);
        arr[0] = 'c';
        arr[1] = 'a';

        return arr;
    }
   ```
3. Make the caller allocate the array and use it as a reference (my recommendation)

   ```
    void my_func(char * arr){

        arr[0] = 'c';
        arr[1] = 'a';
    }
   ```

If you really need the function to return the array, you can return the same reference as:

```
char * my_func(char * arr){
    arr[0] = 'c';
    arr[1] = 'a';
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: There's another perfectly valid option: `return "ca";`.  The hard-coded string is static memory by definition.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a predetermined size of you array you can in-fact return the array if you wrap it with a struct:

```
struct wrap
{
    char a[2] ;
} ;

struct wrap Get( void )
{
    struct wrap w = { 0 } ;

    w.a[0] = 'c';
    w.a[1] = 'a';

return w ;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array to the function and let the function modify it, like this

```
void function(char *array)
 {
    array[0] = 'c';
    array[1] = 'a';
 }
```

and then

```
char array[2];

function(array);
printf("%c%c\n", array[0], array[1]);
```

If you want it as a return value, you should use dynamic memroy allocation,

```
char *function(void)
 {
    char *array;

    array = malloc(2);
    if (array == NULL)
        return NULL;
    array[0] = 'c';
    array[1] = 'a';

    return array;
 }
```

then

```
char *array = function();
printf("%c%c\n", array[0], array[1]);
/* done using `array' so free it because you `malloc'ed it*/
free(array);
```

**Important Note**:

You should be aware of the fact that the array as filled above is not a string, so you can't for instance do this

```
printf("%s\n", array);
```

because the `"%s"` expects a matching string to be passed, and in c an array is not a string unless it's last character is `'\0'`, so for a 2 character string you need to allocate space for 3 characters and set the last one to `'\0'`.

Comment: If you want a null-terminated string, just `return "ca";`.

Answer (score -1):

```
char* getCharArray()
{
  return "ca";
}
```

Comment: It's not wrong.  It's a perfectly valid answer to the original question.  The "above answer" doesn't invalidate it in any way.  My solution doesn't have the problem of returning a pointer to a local variable, because hard-coded strings are static by definition.  The function is perfectly safe and valid.

Answer (score -1):

This works perfecly:

```
int comm_read_data(int file_i2c, unsigned char** buffer)
{
    *buffer = malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    if (i2c_read_bytes(file_i2c, *buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) != 0)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    return BUFFER_SIZE;
}
```

And then call the function:

```
unsigned char* buffer;
int length = comm_read_data(file_i2c, &buffer);

/* parse the buffer here */

free(buffer);
```