# Converting String to Int and returning string again C

Tags: c, visual-studio

I've got an assignment to do at my university.
The assignment is to take a string of some kind, turn it into an integer, do calculation and return the string.

This is what I've done so far, I'm not great at C so any sort of help would be great.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
typedef char* verylong;
verylong multiply_verylong(verylong vl1, verylong vl2);
verylong input_long();
verylong add_verylong(verylong vl1, verylong vl2);


verylong input_long()
{
    verylong string=NULL;
    char arry[1000];
    int input;
    printf("enter your verylong number");
    gets_s("%s",arry);

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (arry[i] == '\n')
        {
            input = i - 1;
            string = (verylong)malloc(i);
            break;
        }
        if ((arry[i] < 48) || (arry[i] > 57))
        {
            printf("invalid number");
            return NULL;
        }
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < input; j++)
    {
        string[j] = arry[j];
    }
    string[input + 1] = '\0';

    return string;
}

verylong add_verylong(verylong vl1, verylong vl2)
{   
    verylong input;
    char res;
    int numofvl1, numofvl2, result, i, j;
    numofvl1 = atoi(vl1);
    numofvl2 = atoi(vl2);
    result = numofvl1 + numofvl2;
    input = (int)malloc(result);
    snprintf(input,10, "%d", result);
    return input;
}
verylong multiply_verylong(verylong vl1, verylong vl2) {
    verylong input;
    int numofvl1, numofvl2, result;
    numofvl1 = atoi(vl1);
    numofvl2 = atoi(vl2);
    result = numofvl1 * numofvl2;
    input = (int)malloc(result);
    snprintf(input, 10, "%d", result);
    return input;
}


void main()
{

    verylong a, b, c;
    do {
        printf("enter the first long integer: ");
        a = input_long();
    } while (!a);
    do {
        printf("enter the second long integer: ");
        b = input_long();
    } while (!b);
    c = add_verylong(a, b);
    printf("%s + %s = %s\n", a, b, c);
    free(c);
    c = multiply_verylong(a, b);
    printf("%s * %s = %s\n", a, b, c);
    free(c);
    free(a);
    free(b);

    system("pause");
}
```

The "verylong input_long()" function is to check if the user have entered a string only from numbers.
If he didnt, it should be returning null and printing invalid number.
about the second function I'm not sure.
I've tried to use atio() but it doesnt seems to be working.

once again, appreciate any sort of help.
thank you guys.

EDIT: something goes wrong with my first function input_long();
if anyone has any idea what i should do it would be great.
I'm suppose to get a string and see if it is all numbers, if its not.
it should print a message and return null

Comment: Use double quotes for strings, not single quotes.

Comment: In `add_verylong`, `result` is an integer, but this function is supposed to return `verylong`, which is not an integer.

Comment: <O/T> it's not good practice to hide pointers in typedefs

Comment: Can you be more specific than, "it doesn't seem to be working"? Are you getting errors or warnings? What are some of the details of your debugging efforts?

Comment: You can use `sprintf()` to write an integer value into a string. But there are some more issues in your code, e.g.: a) **never** use `gets()` it's dangerous ans deprecated b) if your string type is called `verylong` do you expect that you can represent the values in an `int` variable? If not, your calculations would be a little bit more dificult. c) don't cast the result of `malloc()` (search this site for that), d) don't use magic numbers like 48 and 57, but '0' and '9'

Comment: @lurker yes, i am getting Exception thrown at 0x7A0AC4E0 (ucrtbased.dll) in Project11.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x39383937.

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt will do, trying to see if it works, thanks

Comment: You seem to want to handle strings containing numbers with up to 999  digits? This certainly will fail the way you try to handle them: The `int` datatype only has a certain number of bits to represent a number, roughly 32, take one for the sign, and you are left with 2^31 possible numbers in an `int`. That means that the highest number you will be able to keep in an `int` is a decimal number with less than 31 digits (actually, I guess it will be something around 10 ? digits at most)

Comment: @yano I know it doesn't, thats how the lecture requested ;-\

Comment: @dbush Actually, I am rather surprised that this code '9897' even compiles. Single quotes usually denote character constants, and IMHO '9897' does not denote a valid character... If it will be parsed to some sort of character (or multi-byte character), then you certainly run into trouble, since chars are not zero-terminated - they are no valid strings.

Comment: `scanf_s("%s",arry);` is broken code.  Review `scanf_s()` usage.

Comment: `if (arry[i] == '\n')` is never true using `"%s"` as that specifier does not save white-space characters.

Comment: `gets_s("%s",arry);` is an error. you should see an error message, if you don't then change your compiler settings.

Comment: I think you should review what the assignment is. I doubt it's "take a string of some kind, turn it into an integer, do calculation and return the string". There will be more specific details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't return char * like that, see:
[How can I return a character array from a function in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31060404/how-can-i-return-a-character-array-from-a-function-in-c)

Your method can't support more than 19 digits (much less right now, you can support 19 digits if you use unsigned long long).

However if you need to support up to 999 digits I would go with a completely different approach:
You should than do the calculation yourself, digit by digit, that way there is no limit to the number of digits you support (only limited by the size of the input buffer).

Plus in input_long arry will probably end with \0, not \n ,you should check for both.